# Create a multidimesional array using while

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out the best way to handle this. The while loop puts all the data into an array, great! But, i want to group a set of results into an array and put it back into the $row array. And i am not sure how to do that.

The reason being that i want to run a function that will display icons if the grouped items have a value, and i figured grouping them would be easier to work with.

Here is what i have now, it throws an error `Too few arguments to function icon()`, and i understand why its throwing that.

```
    function icon($pump, $product) {
        if ($pump == 'Yes') {
            return "<img src='.." . IMAGES . "icons/icon-pump.png' alt='Trailer has a Pump' class='trailer-icon'>";
        }
        if ($product == 'Yes') {
            return "<img src='.." . IMAGES . "icons/icon-gas.png' alt='Trailer has Product' class='trailer-icon'>";
        }
    }

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $features = array(
            'pump' => $row['trailer_pump'],
            'product' => $row['trailer_product']
        );

        $data = "<tr>\r\n<td><a href='view-trailer.php?id=" . $row['trailer_id'] . "'>" . $row['trailer_number'] . "</a></td>\r\n"
                . "<td>" . $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name'] . "</td>\r\n"
                . "<td>" . icon($features) . "</td>"
                . "<td>" . $row['status_name'] . "</td>\r\n"
                . "<td><a href='https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=" . $row['trailer_lat'] . "," . $row['trailer_long'] . "' target='_blank'>View Map</a></td>\r\n"
                . "</tr>\r\n";
        print $data;
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print $e->getMessage();
}
```

*Update*
The results i am looking for is:

```
    Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [trailer_number] => 609
    [trailer_annual] => 0000-00-00
    [trailer_fiveyear] => 0000-00-00
    [trailer_compartments] => 4
    [features] => array (
           [pump] => Yes
           [product] =>
    )
    [trailer_compart1] => 3000
    [trailer_compart2] => 2000
    [trailer_compart3] => 3000
    [trailer_compart4] => 2000
    [trailer_compart5] => 
)
```

Comment: You want which part to do what exactly?

Comment: The while runs, creates an array $row, then i want to put another array in $row that has the features array.

Comment: So what you want is `$features = array('pump' => array(/*all pumps*/), 'product' => array(/*all products*/))`?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but this `. "<td>" . icon($features) . "</td>"` is obviously missing a parameter!

Comment: Yeah, i'm confused as hell too haha. I updated my question with the array result i am looking for.

Comment: Ahh so you want to ADD the `$features` array into the `$row` array.

Comment: And also REMOVE the 2 original occurances from the `$row` array?

Comment: @RiggsFolly correct

Comment: Is this as well as fix the calling of the `icon` function?

Comment: Still not sure if you are adding to the `$row` array just to pass it all to the `icon` function or if you want the new and improved `$row` for use somewhere else

Comment: @RiggsFolly the icon function would need to be addressed too. Would a `switch` be a better option? Because right now it only runs the first `if` and not the second. I'm sure i can figure this on out, but i am open to suggestions.

Comment: See answer, for getting both possibilities back from the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you changed the function to accept a features array then the function would work

```
function icon(array $feature) {
    if ($feature['pump'] == 'Yes') {
        return "<img src='.." . IMAGES . "icons/icon-pump.png' alt='Trailer has a Pump' class='trailer-icon'>";
    }

    if (!$feature['product'] == 'Yes') {
        return "<img src='.." . IMAGES . "icons/icon-gas.png' alt='Trailer has Product' class='trailer-icon'>";
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could pass the 2 items to the existing function

```
. "<td>" . icon($features['pump'], $features['product']) . "</td>"
```

but this rather negates the point of creating the array in the first place.

Another alternative would be to just use the `$row` data directly and the existing function.

```
. "<td>" . icon($row['trailer_pump'], $row['trailer_product']) . "</td>"
```

and forget about the temporary array completely

UPDATE

Function running both possibilities

```
function icon(array $feature) {
    $ret = '';

    if ($feature['pump'] == 'Yes') {
        $ret .= "<img src='.." . IMAGES . "icons/icon-pump.png' alt='Trailer has a Pump' class='trailer-icon'>";
    }

    if (!$feature['product'] == 'Yes') {
        $ret .= "<img src='.." . IMAGES . "icons/icon-gas.png' alt='Trailer has Product' class='trailer-icon'>";
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: I thought about doing this too, but didn't know about putting `array` into a function.

Comment: So do you also want to add your new features array into the `$row` array? Remember the `$row` array will only exist for the duration of a Loop Iteration, so you would need to do something else with it if you want ed to keep it for use aoutside the WHILE loop

Comment: The location of the function is subjective.  If it can be run inside the loop, that is fine, outside that is fine as well. What you have given me combined with @Cobra_Fast has solved the problem with the exception of including the duplicate data in the array. So trailer_pump appears twice, it's not a big deal if it's not a performance issue.

Comment: Combined with @Cobra_Fast's answer, this worked. Thanks for the help, i appreciate your time!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is simply

```
$row['features'] = array(
    'pump' => $row['trailer_pump'], 
    'product' => $row['trailer_product']
);
```

or if you want to keep `$feautres` the way it already is

```
$row['features'] = $features;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This combined with RiggsFolly, solved my problem. I wish i could award both of you with the answer.